# Listing data that share same data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have three tables:

```
SN | Table Name  | Primary Key   | Foreign Key | Attribute 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1  | salesArea   | salesAreaID   |             | areaDescription
2  | store       | storeID       | salesAreaID | 
3  | salesPerson | salesPersonID | storeID     | salesPersonName
```

I am trying to get the `salesPersonName`(s) of anyone that is in the same `salesArea` as a certain `salesPerson`.

For instance, a `salesPerson` named David works in `storeID` 23, which is in the NE `salesArea`.
There is another `salesPerson` named Bob working in `storeID` 34, which is also in the NE `salesArea`.

My query so far is...

```
SELECT salesPersonName,
salesPersonID,
    st.salesAreaID,
    areaDescription,
    sp.storeId
  FROM salesperson as sp, salesArea as sa, store as st
```

I am confused on how to get it get the `storeID` of 'David' and then retrieve what the `salesArea` is. Then with that `salesArea`, retrieve all `salesPersons` with that `salesArea`.

Salesperson table only gives the `storeID`, but then `store` gives the `salesArea` for the `storeID`s.

Point in the right direction would be nice, join clause? some fancy where with a `group by`?

Comment: Stop using antiquated join syntax like `FROM a, b, c`. Use proper, modern, explicit `INNER JOIN` syntax. Right now you're going to get a cross product because you have no join criteria. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming:

- Areas have stores
- stores have salespersons
- salespersons have names

So, we first want to find the area ID of the salesperson passed:

```
SELECT sp.SalesPersonID, st.SalesAreaID
FROM salesperson as sp
INNER JOIN store as st on sp.StoreID = st.StoreID
WHERE sp.SalesPersonName = 'David'
```

Now, we could use the results of this query to then execute the second part of the question, which is "get the other people in a given salesarea".  If, for example, the above query returned SalesAreaID = 23 and SalesPersonID = 10, our second query would look like the following:

```
SELECT sp.SalesPersonID, sp.SalesPersonName, st.StoreID
FROM stores st
INNER JOIN salespersons sp on st.StoreID = sp.StoreID
WHERE st.SalesAreaID = 23 and sp.SalesPersonID <> 10
```

But, we can combine the two queries to form a single one that does the same thing:

```
SELECT sp2.SalesPersonID, sp2.SalesPersonName, st2.StoreID
FROM salesperson as sp
-- Join to stores to get the areaID of the salesperson passed (multiplicity 1)
INNER JOIN store as st on sp.StoreID = st.StoreID
-- self join to store to get all stores in that area (multiplicity 1 x Stores[area])
INNER JOIN store as st2 on st.SalesAreaID = st2.SalesAreaID
-- get all salespersons assigned to all stores in the area (multiplicity 1 x salespersons[area])
INNER JOIN salesperson as sp2 
    on st2.StoreID = sp2.StoreID 
    -- only return "other" salespersons
    and sp2.SalesPersonID <> sp.SalesPersonID
WHERE sp.SalesPersonName = 'David'
```

Et voilà, we have a query giving all other salespersons in a the same area as a passed salesperson.

Comment: The final query includes the line `and sp2.SalesPersonID <> sp.SalesPersonID` which explicitly excludes 'David'. I.E., if ('Joe', 'Moe', 'David') are in the 'NE' salesArea, and you run this query with 'David', the result set will be ('Joe', 'Moe').  If you want all three, remove or comment out that line.

Comment: @DavidDuke, I'm afraid I had a typo in the original post.  The `sp` table is only David, the `sp2` table has the other rows.  Try the updated query.

Comment: I see, your example is excellent! I will be messing with this for a bit.